# How to plot differenced values on oringinal scale

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an array MA1 of 5000 values I want to take the difference of every 100th value and then divide by 100 to get the gradient between every 100th point.
I would then like to plot the MA1 data and the gradients on the same graph so that the gradient starting at point 100 is shown at point 100 on the graph how can I do this?
Right now MA1 is indexed 1:5000 while C is only 1:500. I want C to appear in every 100th place for MA1 but I don't want anything in between.

```
 MA1=rand(5000);
 N=100;
 B=MA1(1:N:length(MA1));
 C=diff(B)/N;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
dataLen = 50;
MA1 = rand(1, dataLen);
N   = 5;
B   = MA1(1:N:length(MA1));
C   = diff(B) / N;
D   = N:N:(length(MA1) - N);

figure;
hold on;
plot(1:dataLen, MA1);
plot(D, C, 'ko', 'MarkerSize', 8, 'LineWidth', 4);
hold off;
```

Here is a figure I generated using the above code - but only going from 1:50 with gradients in steps of 5;

[image]